# Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) CWE ID 80

Tags: c#, html, tags, xss

I run my application with VERACODE tool but I got struggling with some issues.

One of the issue which I face is Improper Neutralization of the Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80). 
This happens in many screens in my application.
In the following particular line:

```
NewDivButton.Style["display"] = SearchParameters.NewDivButtonVisibility;
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on  how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Consider including details of what language/stack you're working in, as well as what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Manikandan. The best answer to this question would involve knowledge of the language/framework you're using if you could share that?

One thing to note, is that there are many things you could do that would make the warning "go away", but wouldn't make your app any more secure. For that reason, it's best to understand the core of the problem, and then apply the standard fix for the language/framework you're working in. If in doubt, check with a security professional.

In general, XSS is a set of issues where you (potentially) render user input as part of your output.
In this example if I send you a link that says yoursite.com?NewDivButtonVisibility=">SendYourPrivateInfoSomewhereBad();
If you click a link like this, and the site blindly inserts the script into the page, it could steal data.
The best protection is often to validate input, only allowing known-valid input through.
Another common approach is to HTML-encode the unknown value being displayed. However, more care is needed depending on where the output is rendered (e.g. if already within a script tag)

There's much more general information on this type of issue here: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#cross-site-scripting-prevention-cheat-sheet